# Having trouble accessing elements of a vector inside loop

Tags: rust

I am trying to print the elements of a vector through the println! inside a loop.

This is the error I get, cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Please advise!

```
error[E0277]: the type `[i32]` cannot be indexed by `i32`
   |
21 |         s = v[outercount];
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[i32]>` is not implemented for `i32`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<i32>` for `std::vec::Vec<i32>`
```

```
let v = vec![1,4,2,4,1,8];
let mut outercount:i32 = 0;
loop {
    outercount += 1;
    s = v[outercount];
    println!("{}", s);
    if outercount == (v.len() - 1) as i32 { break; }
}
```

Comment: 1. this is not idiomatic rust 2. the compiler tell you why 3.you need to use a `usize` to index a vector

Comment: @Stargateur, I understand the error message, but didn't know how to put it in code. could you help, please.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not doing a `for` loop? `for s in &v { print!("{}", s); }`

Comment: @loganfsmyth I have cut down my code to make it simple to post it here. I have a for loop with enumerate inside this loop. If I use a for loop like the way you mentioned how do I make the outercount variable step to the next element in the vector?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what structure you're describing.

Comment: Totally fine loganfsmyth, The below answer worked. Thanks to Psidom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, index needs to be `usize` instead of `i32`:

```
let v = vec![1,4,2,4,1,8];
let mut outercount: usize = 0;    // declare outercount as usize instead of i32
loop {
    let s = v[outercount];        // need to declare variable here
    println!("{}", s);
    outercount += 1;
    if outercount == v.len() { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this may not actually help your code @Sumchans, but I'm compelled to write a [more idiomatic](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4243a28662453ca53c1c40344ebe26b4) version. I hope that it helps someone:

```
fn main() {
   let v = vec![1,4,2,4,1,8];
   v.iter().for_each(|n| println!("{}", n));
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `for n in &v { println!("{}", n); }`. It is more readily understood and equally idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks @matiu , all your answers they do really help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @trentcl. Learned about a few ways to implement the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem few days ago but in a different manner when I was trying to make my bubble sort program in rust. I hope you got your answer as I can see. I think the way you wanted to print a vector is syntactically incorrect, here is an example of printing a vector in a loop. Hope this would help you.

```
fn main(){
let v = vec![1,3,5,7,9]; 
for i in v.iter(){ //also for i in &v 
  println!("{:?}",i);
 }
}
```

Also you can use

```
let outercount = v[0]; //rust will automatically infer this as [i32]
```

Comment: This would definitely help.  Thanks @Taimoor.

Comment: Its  always pleasure to help fellow developers.